# "\" Symbol Getting Replaced with " " in Window.Open

Tags: javascript

I have a Hyperlink where I am Calling a function Openlink which is a follows

```
function OpenLink()
{
    window.open("http://192.168.1.21/Sample/download.asp?Filename=Sample.html&Filepath=E:\Sample\Folder\PRINTSCREEN\"","","toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=400,height=100,top=10,left=200'")
}

<a href='#' onclick="OpenLink()"><font color=BLUE><b>FileName</b></font></a>
```

When I click on the HyperLink, It calls the function but after the Filepath, all the "\" is getting replaced by empty("") that is why it is not finding the correct file path.Please Help. I tried by giving "\" in this and it coming properly But I only want by giving a single "\". Please help

Comment: The backslash ( \ ) is an escape character in Javascript. This means that when Javascript encounters a backslash, it tries to escape the  character.

To work around this, you need to escape it. That means \\ will output a single backslash (and \\\\ will output two, and so on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your URL is not properly URL encoded:

```
&Filepath=E:\Sample\Folder\PRINTSCREEN
```

Should be:

```
&Filepath=E%3A%5CSample%5CFolder%5CPRINTSCREEN
```

You can use this code to apply the proper escaping:

```
var url = 'http://192.168.1.21/Sample/download.asp?Filename=Sample.html&Filepath=' +
    encodeURIComponent('E:\\Sample\\Folder\\PRINTSCREEN'),
options = 'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=400,height=100,top=10,left=200';

window.open(url, '', options);
```

As you can see the backslashes in JavaScript strings must be escaped with another backslash; however, in a URL, they just need to be encoded.

See also: [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Well I tried escaping the back slash "\" with "%5C" but still the request sent gets it completely omitted. This happened for me in firefox and chrome ... not sure about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra **double-quotation(`"`)** in specifying the `URL` in `window.open()` and an extra single-quotation(`'`) in specifying the `specs` in `window.open()`. Corrected those.

Use the following:

```
window.open("http://192.168.1.21/Sample/download.asp?Filename=Sample.html&Filepath=E:/Sample/Folder/PRINTSCREEN","","toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=400,height=100,top=10,left=200'")
```